# Miktex: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips'

Tags: latex, miktex

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7, and when I want to create my pdf file I get:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',
(hyperref)                because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've asked the `hyperref` package to work in `dvips`-mode, but are trying to compile it through `pdfTeX`.

My guess would be you either:

- Have set the option `dvips` in your `\documentclass`.
  An example of this would be:

  ```
  \documentclass[dvips]{article}
  ```
- Have set the option `dvips` in your `\usepackage` for `hyperref`.
  An example of this would be:

  ```
  \usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
  ```

If you're doing either of those two things, you're actively telling the package that you're using `dvips`, which you're not, so it's failing.

You should be able to resolve the problem by either:

- Removing `dvips` from the options list.
- Replacing `dvips` with `pdftex`.

If none of these options are set, try setting the `pdftex` option on your `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: I tried all you said and nothing worked. Keep getting the same error message. However my problem is a bit different: Here is the error message (am using texilve 2021)    !Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI driver option 'ps2pdf' because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just had to use a decent TeX Editor, as WinEdit.

I run [`texify`](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texifying.html) to create a `.dvi` file and then `dvi2pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was: hyperref error: wrong dvi mode driver option `ps2pdf'

I had to edit the file:
sudo vi /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings-ext/hyperref.cfg

The first few lines were:

```
\ProvidesFile{hyperref.cfg}%
  [2009/08/23 v1.0 hyperref configuration of listings-ext]
\providecommand*{\Hy@defaultdriver}{hdvips}%

\hypersetup{
  ps2pdf,                     % the documentation uses ps2pdf
```

I replaced "ps2pdf" by "pdftex"

That solved my problem.